# How to access heap space of a program by using another program?

Tags: memory, operating-system, heap-memory

Consider I have a case where i have executed a program and created an instance of a class,

```
MyClass mClass = new MyClass()
```

After the execution the Reference Space will be stored in the Heap Space. Now I want to write a Program which can access the Heap Space to retrieve the data from the Previously created instance of another program.
Can I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, in practice, no. If you give the other program admin privileges, you can read the memory of another program, but as far as I know there is no way to know for sure where the heap of that program resides. (There are probably hacky ways to achieve this, but it's not going to be pretty or reliable).

However, it is possible for a process to establish a region of [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) that another process can read, or use sockets, but this requires co-operation between the processes. Also, it still doesn't give a process direct access to another process' heap - your program can only see what the other process lets it see.

Note that, while you can't change the behavior of `new` (as far as I know), there is nothing preventing you from writing code to manage your heap manually; in that sense it would be possible to place the heap directly in the shared memory region. Whether that would be wise or not is another question and, obviously, highly dependent on the context.

In order to fully understand how operating systems manage memory, you'll have to understand [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) and [memory management hardware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) (you'll probably want to go deeper than Wikipedia, though) .

Answer (score 0):

Well i think you can use sockets for accessing the Heap Space. I hope this works.